# Why has my error handler stoppped working at macro's first error

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

All of my error handlers have stopped working all together on my desktop and for the life of me I can't figure out why. Even running the basic code below has an error message pop up at the line `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B2")` instead of going to SectionA. Does anyone know how to fix this? Also just for reference this only started recently and my laptop handles errors just fine.

```
Sub Macro1()
    On Error GoTo SectionA
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B2")
    Range("B2:B6").Select
    SectionA:
End Sub
```

Comment: In the VB Editor window go to Tools --> Options --> General --> Error Trapping and click Break in Class Module and see if that works.

Comment: Seems like your current setting is "Break on all errors"